# sitecore shorten url doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am trying to shorten url of a site that my company develop using sitecore. I have been looking into Alex Shyba's blog post [here](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2012/02/have-sitecorecontent-in-your-link-time.html) and Sitecore documentation [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc62keywords/dynamic_links_sc62_a4.pdf), but it seems doesn't work. What I want to shorten is from `localhost:8081/sitecore/Content/Sites/HeinzABCID/Dapur.aspx` to `localhost:8081/Dapur.aspx`

That url is generated by `LinkManager.GetItemUrl()` method. My code is like below to get the option and the link.

```
UrlOptions opt = (UrlOptions)UrlOptions.DefaultOptions.Clone();
opt.SiteResolving = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving;
linkToResep.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(citem, opt);
```

While in my `web.config` I have put the configuration like below.

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
         addAspxExtension="true"
         alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"
         encodeNames="true"
         languageEmbedding="asNeeded"
         languageLocation="filePath"
         shortenUrls="true"
         useDisplayName="true"/>
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

The `configuration/sitecore/sites/site` with `name="website"` part in my web.config is below.

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/Content/Sites/HeinzABCID" startItem="/Home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" language="en" disableClientData="false"/>
```

I don't have any other site, just that with default(shell, login, admin, service, modules_shell, and modules_website).

And here is the site structure of my site.

```
/sitecore/content/sites
    +Sites
    +---+HeinzABCID
        +---+Dapur
            +Search
            +Other Items
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Are you sure your site settings are correct? These issues could raise when the site setting is not correct and you are linking to an item which is not within the root of your website.

Comment: As Martijn has suggested, post the "website" element from the your <sites> section of your config. If you are using patch include files then make sure you view the merged config using Rocks or via http://<site>/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Comment: @MartijnvanderPut and @jammykam I have added the website part in my `web.config`. Sorry for I forgot to add that before.

Comment: I currently have a bug registered with Sitecore, because LinkManager.GetItemUrl() ignores Rendering.SiteResolver and I've had them prioritize this problem, but no word on a solution yet. There is a description of the problem (and solution) here: http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/using-cross-site-links-dynamic-links/

Comment: @Holger I saw that you create a class and a custom method of GetItemUrl, won't it be the same as the code that I post on my question? CMIIW I have also added my tree structure to the **Dapur** `Item` on my question. Thank you.

Comment: This was working as of 6.4, it looks like you have a multisite implementation? Can you try adding `hostName="localhost:8081" targetHostName="localhost:8081"` to your `<site>` node as suggested in the linked article.

Comment: @didityedi Ah yeah that is the sames, sorry for not seeing that, and I think the solution is to use targetHostName (which is required if you hostName has wildcards or ambiguiety). as jammykam says

Comment: @jammykam it returns _Site from host name and path was not found. Host: localhost, path: /dapur.aspx_

Comment: Maybe the port numbers are throwing it? I suggest you add an entry to your hosts file `127.0.0.1 HeinzABCID`, add as a host header to the site in IIS instead of port number and change the above to HeinzABCID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex replace I successfully shorten the URL. I can also manage to use it on multiple site.

```
public static string ShortenURL(string URLToShorten)
{
    return Regex.Replace(URLToShorten,@"sitecore/content/sites/[\w]{1,}/","");
}
```

The complete description of the solution that includes SEO can be found [here](http://adityayedija.wordpress.com/2013/03/31/sitecore-shortening-url-for-your-seo-sake/).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, with /sitecore/content/site showing up in my URLs.

In my case it was site context that was wrong - running the sitecore shell context instead of the website context. Here's the code used to switch:

```
// Store the current site context name
string oldSiteName = Sitecore.Context.GetSiteName();

// Change the website context
Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("website");

// Generate the link
string url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);

// Change back to the old site context
Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite(oldSiteName);
```

Comment: i tried the same too that time, but still shows the same error. that is why i am using regex in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your site configuration is incorrect.  Based on your Sitecore tree I think it should be:

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/Content/Sites" startItem="/HeinzABCID" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" language="en" disableClientData="false"/>
```

You may also want to look at this article on Sitecore SDN for configuring multiple sites in a single Sitecore instance: 
[Sitecore SDN: Configuring Multiple Sites](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx)

According to this documentation, the URL will be created relative to the 'startItem' as defined in your 'website' site tag.

Comment: It is still not working after a long trial and error. I have posted the answer as I have using other method instead of sitecore default method.

Answer (score 0):

It may also help if your site definition has a targethostname defined.